# how to access Citadel admin interface from external computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mail-server

How can I access the Citadel admin web interface from an external computer? I've tried to open the port used in the firewall, but without luck

Answer (score 0):

Using Red Hat/centos 7, open port by

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=[yourport]/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

If you're on a VM, make sure it can ping the host.

For host/VM communication, virtualbox has an interface on your host; assign an IP like 192.168.1.1.
Then on the VM settings, assign the interface to host only.

Then in your Linux VM set interface IP like 192.168.1.10
and reload the network.

You should have now access to citadel in your browser by typing `[ip.of.the.vm:yourport]`.